# flash class definition not found in classpath

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash

when i try and validate the class definition from the symbol, it says it cant find the class definition in the class path.

things i have checked(a few times):

the file is in the same folder as the FLA,
its named the same as the class,
the objects linkage has the same name as the class,
the source path only has one entry witch is "."

my code is

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class homeGenListButton extends MovieClip {


    public function homeGenListButton() {
        // constructor code
        trace("here");
        //var txtField:TextField = this.getChildByName("GenListTxt");
        //txtField.text = "text2";


    }
}

}
```

I am using action script 3, with flash professional CS6.
an image of the error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP3Hf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Based on your pic, the problem is in class names and inheritance which is kind of conflicting because... well I can't be sure but when you start mixing classes this way, it is much better to start developing in FlashDevelop.

However, I was able to fix your case, but with a different approach:

1. Keep your class as .as package/file, extend it from MovieClip and name somewhat differently, let's say homeGenListButtonProto:

> ```
> package  {
>   import flash.display.MovieClip;
>   public class homeGenListButtonProto extends MovieClip {
>        public function homeGenListButtonProto() {
>           trace('well hello!');
>        }
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Now while adding your button class in the Flash library, use homeGenListButton as a class name and homeGenListButtonProto as a base class (instead of flash.display.Movieclip). It will work that way. Effectively, homeGenListButton (in the library) extends homeGenListButtonProto (in the .as file) which extends MovieClip. Not a very elegant solution but I'm afraid there is no other way unless you start to use FlashDevelop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the slow response :/ , I am trying to link a symbol to a class. here is a picture to hopefully better describe what I am trying to do better. [image](http://i.imgur.com/tEdKAWA.png)

Comment: Using this method it finds the proto and runs the code fine, it says it does not find the "homeGenListButton" still but it seems to behave just the same way. thank!! :) unfortunately i cant give u an upvote though :( (not enough rep)